# fail2ban actions to broaden the banned IP range

Tags: fail2ban

Is there a way to have fail2ban ban the entire class C network from which a ban address comes from?

A

Comment: I haven't thought about it before, but maybe it can be done by using a fail2ban action script. The challenge maybe on whether this ban will be done temporary or permanently (easier).

Comment: You can set jail time to permanent if you use -1. So that can be taken care of, banning class C networks might help cut down the number of required entries to clean things up a bit.  I have been using IPTABLES as well..

Answer (score 3):

As fail2ban adds rules to iptables, You may prefer to use iptables directly

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 197.198.199.0/24 -j DROP
```

fail2ban can block an ip range, see how with the client:

```
# fail2ban-client -v set [JailName] banip 197.198.199.0/24
# example:

fail2ban-client -v set recidive banip 197.198.199.0/24
```

Since jails are time limited, iptables could be a better idea, depending of what you want/need.

But, to answer your question :
Someone have done a configuration customization to ban the whole network of an ip sent in jail
See: https://www.righter.ch/index.php/2014/12/10/block-a-whole-ip-range-with-fail2ban/

Comment: I'll have a look and get back to you.

Comment: Using the client isn't what I had in mind.  I s'pose the tricky part is, extracting the first three quarters of the address and attaching the 0/24 to the end for the IP to ban.

Comment: @A.Adverse I have reread your question again : there is no out-of-the-box rule or action to ban the whole network of an ip sent in jail. But someone have done it: https://www.righter.ch/index.php/2014/12/10/block-a-whole-ip-range-with-fail2ban/